# removing button dynamically

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5nZRh/6/),under appointments tab,there is a add timing button.When this button is clicked then a new row is added along with another add timing button.But I did not want another add timing buttons so i made this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5nZRh/10/)

added a class timing

```
<button class="btn btn-primary timing" type="button" data-bind="click: $parent.addSlot" value="Add">Add Timing</button>
```

and 
in js

```
self.addSlot = function () { 
    //self.schedules.push(new Model.Schedule(null));
    console.log('added');
    self.doctor.schedules.push(new Schedule(null));
    $('.timing:last').hide();
    };
```

now the problem in the above fiddles there is one JSON so initally only one add timing button is added but if the JSON is 2 then 2 add timings button are added like this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5nZRh/12/)

so can any body please tell me how will I have only on add timings button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move the `Add Timing` button outside the table and access the `$root` context instead of the `$parent` context

```
<!-- ... -->
</table>

<button class="btn btn-primary timing" type="button" data-bind="click: $root.addSlot" value="Add">Add Timing</button>
```

This way the `Add Timing` button will not be duplicated with every entry. You must also remove the

```
$('.timing:last').hide();
```

Otherwise, the button will be hidden on your first adding.

See updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5nZRh/13/)

*Update:*

According to [Binding context](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html), `$data` works equally well in this case

```
data-bind="click: $data.addSlot"
```

See another [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5nZRh/14/)